# How to open ContextMenu by using keyboard shortcut

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I create WPF DataGrid with ContextMenu in one of column header as follow:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders}">
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ShowStatusHeaderContextMenuCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FristNameContextMenu}"
                        Gesture="Ctrl+S" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30" Header="Status">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="StatusHeaderTextBlock" Text="Status">
                      <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu x:Name="FristNameContextMenu">
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding SetCompleteFlagsCommand}" Header="Complete"/>
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding ClearDeleteFlagsCommand}" Header="Deleted" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                      </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                  </TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

         <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"
                             Header="Order Number"
                             Binding = "{Binding Path=OrderNumber}"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If I right click on Status column header, it brings up the ContextMenu. But I want to add a shortcut key "Control + S" to bring up the ContextMenu as well. Anyone know how to add it?

Thanks

Jing

Comment: you can listen for "KeyboardEvent" which should be solution for you, to open context menu in selected location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) that opens the context menu and add a [`KeyBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) with that command and your gesture to the [`InputBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx) of the control in whose scope the shortcut should apply.

(Also: `Ctrl+S` is "Save" by convention, i am not sure if you really want to use that for a context menu)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added `InputBinding` on the control and `Command` at code behind. How do I open the context menu in the Command execute. Currently I cannot access the context menu to set the `IsOpen` to `True`

Comment: @Jing: You could pass the `ContextMenu` as command parameter (via binding), or you bind the `IsOpen` to some property and your command just sets that property to true.

Comment: I tried both.both are not working. I tried passing `ContextMenu` as command parameter, but only get `null`. I updated my post so you can have a look.

Comment: @Jing: Of course that does not work, the ContextMenu is inside a template, the control is in a different name-scope you cannot bind to it from the outside. What you could do is define the context menu as a resource, then you can pass it via StaticResource and use it in the template via StaticResource as well.